# Discrete Distribution

Tags: self-study, distributions, density-function, uniform-distribution

In the die-coin experiment, a fair, standard die is rolled and then a fair coin is tossed the number of times showing on the die. Let N denote the die score and Y the number of heads.

a)I want to find the probability density function of N and b)i want to Find the probability density function of Y.

Answer: How to solve this question? I am working on it.

Comment: Neither $N$ nor $Y$ can have a pdf, because--as your title asserts--they have discrete distributions.

Comment: See the `self-study` [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) which explains something about how these sorts of questions are asked and answered. What have you done so far? Do you know anything about the relationships between joint, conditional and marginal probability?

Comment: @Glen_b i have calculated the answer.So i shall answer my own question, when i revisit this stats.stackexchange site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer**

**a)** $g(n)=\frac16 for n \in {[1,2,3,4,5,6]}$ .This is a uniform distribution on {1,2,3,4,5,6}

**b)** $h(0)=\frac{63}{384},h(1)=\frac{120}{384},h(2)=\frac{99}{384},h(3)=\frac{64}{384},h(4)=\frac{29}{384},h(5)=\frac{8}{384},h(6)=\frac{1}{384}$

I think no explanation is needed to the answer **a)**

Now, let us proceed to the answer **b)**. To arrive at the final answer, we use binomial probability distribution. The expected value of number of points on the roll of a die is 3.5. The random variable Y(number of heads) takes the value{0,1,2,3,4,5,6}. The probability of 0 number of head in a single toss is 0.5. Likewise the probability of 5 heads in 6 tosses is $\binom{6}{5}(0.5)^6$
So, the probability of 0 heads in single toss, 2 tosses, 3 tosses, 4 tosses, 5 tosses and lastly 6 tosses is 0.5,0.25,0.125,0.0625,0.03125,0.015625 respectively. So its total is 0.984375. 
We should multiply 0.984375 with expected value 3.5. The result devided by 21 (the total of number of points on the roll of a die) we get $\frac{63}{384}$

If we follow this procedure to calculate 1,2,3,4,5,6 number of heads with 1,2,3,4,5,6 number of tosses,we get the probability distribution of number of heads on the number of times showing on the die,a fair standard coin is tossed.

Comment: detailed answer will be provided but not now.

Comment: Your explanation suggests you got the correct answer only by accident.  The effect of multiplying by the expectation and dividing by the total is to multiply by $1/6$.  This works *only* because the distribution of the outcomes on the die is uniform, with a chance of $1/6$ for every one of the outcomes.  In any other case of a non-uniform distribution your recipe would produce an incorrect answer.

Comment: @whuber, I have calculated this answer using my thought process. Would you  give me any example of non-uniform distribution?

Comment: Sure.  Let's take an extreme case of a die that is loaded to land either 3 or 4 with equal probability; it will almost never land 1, 2, 5, or 6. Its expectation is still 3.5 and the total of all possible values is still 21. It should be obvious, though, that now the chance of observing more than 4 heads is practically zero.